# $S(x,r)$is not convex in a normed space

Tags: functional-analysis

Please, can somebody tell me if it correct what I worked?
I have the following problem:
Let $X$ be a  real normed space, with $X$ nonempty, $x \in X$ and define the set:$$S=S(x,r)=\{y\in X:||y-x||=r$$, where $r>0$. I have to prove that this set is not convex.
My attempt:suppose is convex. Then, for every $a,b \in S$ and $t \in [0,1]$, we will have that: $ta+(1-t)b \in S$. Let $a$ and $b$, $a \neq b$ be elements of $S$; then,$$||a-x||=||b-x||=r$$; for $t=\frac{1}{2}$, we have that $||\frac{a}{2}+\frac{b}{2}-x||=r$, as $S$ is convex. But:$$r=||\frac{a}{2}+\frac{b}{2}-x||\le||\frac{a}{2}-\frac{x}{2}||+||\frac{b}{2}-\frac{x}{2}||\le \frac{1}{2}||a-x||+\frac{1}{2}||b-x||=r$$.So we have equality in the inequality of module, so exists a $\lambda>0$, such that: $$\frac{a}{2}-\frac{x}{2}=\lambda(\frac{b}{2}-\frac{x}{2})$$.By taking norms, we will have that:$\frac{r}{2}=\frac{|\lambda| r}{2}$, so $|\lambda|=1$ and $\lambda=1$, which implies that $a=b$, contradiction.

Comment: How do you conclude $\lambda = 1$?

Comment: (to make this more precise: how do you exclude $\lambda = -1$?)

Comment: Then there is something wrong. Take $x=0$ and $a= -b$ such that $||a||=r$. Then also $||b||=r$. This does not show the claim is wrong, but there is something wrong with the reasoning. Also there are norms in $\mathbb{R}^n$ where the sets $||x||= r$ are composed of parts of hyperplanes, i.e. of convex sets. In general you will not be able to conclude that the convexity relation is not true for every pair $a,b$. You need to find special pairs (like $a$ and $-a$ in case $x=0$).

Comment: And how can I fix it? A suggestion, please?

Comment: Would it be for any help if for $x \neq 0$, to observ that $(1+\frac{r}{||x||})x$ is in $S$?

Comment: In case $X = \{0\}$ your set $S$ is empty, hence convex.

Comment: I'd specifically inspect the case $x+a$ and $x-a$, for which the convex combination is the line through two opposite points in the sphere. So it would contain $x$ itself, which is absurd.

Comment: Could you be more specific, please?if $a \in S$, then $||a-x||=r$;but why $||x+a||$ is also r?

Comment: Your are not interested in $||x-a||$ and $||x+a||$, but in $||x-(x-a)||=||a||$ and $||x-(x+a)||= ||a||$

Comment: I didnt actually get it..if $x+a $ and $x-a$ are opposite points on the sphere, the line which unites then passes trough the center $x$..I dont understand why its absurd it contains $x$

Comment: If it contains $x$ and if the sphere where convex, then $x$ is on the sphere of radius $r$ around $x$ (Because convexity just means if you have to points in the convex set then the straight line joining them is contained in the convex set as well). This is absurd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look, for $v\neq0$,  at $c(t)= x+tv$. For $t=0$ you get $||c(0)-x||=0$. For $t\rightarrow \infty$ you get $||c(t)-x||\rightarrow \infty$. Similarly for $t\rightarrow -\infty$. So, for given $r>0$, by continuity and the mean value theorem you'll find $t_1, t_2 >0 $ such that $||c(t_1)-x || = ||c(-t_2)-x|| = r$. Now look at the line $tc(t_1)+(1-t)c(-t_2), 0\le t\le 1,$ joining $c(t_1)$ and $c(-t_2)$ which passes through $x$. You'll actually find $t_1= t_2$, but that does not matter.

Edit 1: The mean value theorem is applied to the continuous functions $t\mapsto ||x+tv||\, 0\le t\le \infty$, which has attains the value  $0$ as well as arbitrary large values, and therefore, by the mean value theorem, any positive real number as value.

Edit 2: this approach is far to complicated, here is how it can be done simpler: let $v\in S(x, r)$ and $a= v-x$, so $||a||= r$. Then let $w = x+a$. So $||w-x||=||x+a-x||=||a||=  r$, which just means $w\in S(x,r)$. Conseqently, $$\frac{v+w}{2} =\frac{x+a + x-a}{2} = x$$ is a  convex combination of two elements of $S(x,r)$. If the latter set were convex, then this would  implie $x\in S(x,r) \Rightarrow ||x-x||= r \Rightarrow r = 0$.

Comment: One last question, Thomas..can you detail a bit how you applied the mean value theorem to find $t_{1}$ and $t_{2}$ with that properties?Thank you!

Comment: @user308560 I edited my answer. Hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Thomas's approach is correct, but obscured by technicalities. By linearity arguments it is sufficent to show that $S = S(\bar 0 ,1)$ is not convex.

Take any $x \in S$. Then $-x \in S$. If $S$ was convex, then $ \bar 0 = \frac 12 x + \frac 12 (-x)$ were in $S$. But it obviously is not, because $\| \bar 0 \| = 0 \neq 1$. So $S$ is not convex.

Comment: this is what you could have found in my 'Edit 2'.

Comment: Yes, but it might be hard to follow. When i think about a sphere i always think about S. Any other sphere behaves the same.

Comment: Just wanted to present this point of view